# Overstory-understory classification from discrete return aerial LiDAR

Tags: lidar, classification, forest-ecology, wildlife-ecology

I have an opportunity to collaborate with bat biologists who are interested in predicting probability of roost occurence in seasonally flooded ponderosa woodland. We suspect that both properties of canopy and understory are relevant, and I hoped to extract metrics from each, eg, rumpleness and density, from a discrete return aerial LiDAR point cloud. My impression of the system is that there are single overstory trees with a predominantly herbaceous understory, and I'm wondering if there are useful tools for binarizing the cloud into overstory and understory in such a system. I've found recent methods that look for dips in histograms of Z values in a moving (XY) window, and make a cut at the dip. I'm wondering if there is a good candidate algorithm (currently published and implemented) that could perform this task?

Comment: Could you supply an XY coordinate in a region representative of the plant community type? This will help us get a sense of the forest structure.

Comment: ...also, it would be very simple to set a height threshold so that all points above the threshold are classified as overstory and all points under the threshold are classified as understory. Is this what you are after?

Comment: [Here's where we're working.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/46°40'22.8%22N+114°02'30.6%22W/@46.673004,-114.0435126,1108m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m13!1m6!3m5!1s0x535c2bdb95001fbd:0x83c4d3fd83fac6ea!2sMPG+Ranch!8m2!3d46.6681325!4d-114.0267825!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d46.6730041!4d-114.0418191) I have tried a height cutoff approach (< 3m = understory). I'm not entirely sure how this will impact the metrics I'm interested in. For example, how will rumpleness be influenced by the presence of branches reaching down into the understory from above the 3m cut?

Comment: Have you read this classic LiDAR paper which uses a predictive modeling approach to map understory shrubs and snags for bird habitat suitability? https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2009_martinuzzi_s002.pdf @JeffreyEvans

Comment: Thanks, I had not read that. Much to digest there.

Comment: All of the discrete return lidar metrics used in Martinuzzi et all (2009) are described in Evans et al., (2009) and can be derived using the lidR package.  https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/1/4/776